# Can't instantiate new Javascript class - Test failing

Tags: javascript, class

Why my class initiation isn't resetting to the defaultConfig? See the failing test.

class file

```
// class file
const defaultConfig = {
  color: 'blue',
  texture: 'rough'
}
class BaseClass {
  constructor(config) {
    this.config = Object.assign({}, defaultConfig, config);
    this.color = this.config.color
    this.texture = this.config.texture
  }
}

module.exports = BaseClass
```

Test File

```
// test file
const BaseClass = require('./BaseClass')
describe('class', () => {
  it('instantiates base', () => {
    const base = new BaseClass({})
    expect(base.color).toBe('blue')
    expect(base.texture).toBe('rough')
  })
  it('instantiates smooth', () => {
    const smooth = new BaseClass({ texture: 'smooth' })

    expect(smooth.color).toBe('blue')
    expect(smooth.texture).toBe('smooth')
  })

  it('instantiates green', () => {
    const green = new BaseClass({ color: 'green' })

    expect(green.color).toBe('green')
    // FAILS! Texture
    expect(green.texture).toBe('rough') // rough is the default, should be rough
  })
})
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this behavior in the browser (just with the class definition and the instantiation of `green`). Where are you seeing this behavior?

Comment: Wow, you're right... so this is a simplified version of the class i'm dealing with, but if this didn't reproduce it it must be something else